# What is the use case for var in ES6?

Tags: ecmascript-6

If the `let` keyword introduces a proper implementation of block scope, does `var` any longer have a use case? I am looking at this from a software design standpoint rather than a syntactical, "well you could" standpoint.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/javascript-let-keyword-vs-var-keyword

Comment: I understand the difference, I am just trying to pick programming brains right now for why `var` will not just leave common usage forever.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between using "let" and "var" to declare a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> If the `let` keyword introduces a proper implementation of block scope, does `var` any longer have a use case?

There could be one use case: `let` declarations in global scope don't create a property on the global object. Example:

```js
"use strict"; // for chrome
var foo = 42;
let bar = 21;
console.log('window.foo (var)', window.foo); // 42
console.log('window.bar (let)', window.bar); // undefined
```

From [8.1.1.4 Global Environment Records](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-global-environment-records)

> The object [Environment Record](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-environment-records) component of a global Environment Record contains the bindings for all built-in globals ([clause 18](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-global-object)) and all bindings introduced by a *FunctionDeclaration*, *GeneratorDeclaration*, or *VariableStatement* contained in global code. The bindings for all other ECMAScript declarations in global code are contained in the declarative Environment Record component of the global Environment Record.

However, this can also easily be solved by creating an **explicit** global variable using by assigning to the global object directly:

```
window.foo = 42;
```

This would also be the only way to create global classes btw, because the `class` declaration has the same behavior.

(Note: I'm not advocating the use of global variables)

---

There are syntax constructs where you can only use `var`, but that's more a consequence of the how the spec evolved and doesn't really serve any practical purpose. For example:

```
if (true)
  var foo = 42; // valid but kind of useless or bad design

// vs

if (true)
  let foo = 42; // invalid
```

---

Block scope is not the only useful feature though. The [*temporal dead zone*](http://jsrocks.org/2015/01/temporal-dead-zone-tdz-demystified/) is another handy feature to find bugs more easily. Compare:

```
var foo = 42;
function bar() {
  console.log(foo); // undefined
  var foo = 21;
}
bar();

// vs

var foo = 42; // or `let`, doesn't matter
function bar() {
  console.log(foo); // ReferenceError, temporal dead zone
  let foo = 21;
}
bar();
```

You get a reference error when trying to access a `let` variable that wasn't initialized yet.

Comment: From what you're saying, it seems like `let` introduces a stricter environment for business logic. It's my opinion that it has to phase the use of `var` out over time in enlightened circles.

Comment: why does the let declaration after the if statement fail without curly braces?  , ie `if (true) let foo = 42; // invalid`, whereas `if (true){ let foo = 42; // valid }`

Comment: @user1063287: Just from a practical perspective there is no point in declaring a variable that cannot be accessed anywhere else (the `let` variable wouldn't be visible outside the `if` statement but there is no other statement in the `if` statement). From a grammar perspective, an `if` statement's body has to be a *Statement*. A `let` "statement" is a *LexicalDeclaration*, which is a *Declaration* but **not** a *Statement*. But a *BlockStatement* (`{...}`) can contain a list of *Statement*s and *Declaration*s.

Answer (score 6):

`let` can't be used in global scope ***yet***. `var` can.

This is what you get from Chrome when you try a global `let` outside of strict mode:

> Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Comment: Is this a result from the spec itself or current implementations?

Comment: @KamuelaFranco: Apparently an implementation limitation

Answer (score 5):

Practically there may be some use-cases.

###### 1. Declare variable in try-catch like so:

```
try {
    //inits/checks code etc
    let id = getId(obj);

    var result = getResult(id);
} catch (e) {
    handleException(e);
}

//use `result`
```

With `let` the `result` declaration would be before `try`, - a bit early and out of context.

###### 2. Same for conditional declarations:

```
if (opts.re) {
    var re = new RegExp(opts.re);
    var result = match(re);
    if (!result) return false;
}

// result is available here
```

With `let` this code would be forced to complain "good style", though that might be impractical.

###### 3. Loop block:

```
for (var x = 0; x < data.width; x++) {
    if (data[x] == null) break;
    //some drawing/other code
}

//`x` pointing to the end of data
```

Some may consider that untidy, I myself prefer `let`s, but if code I already has `var`s - that's natural to keep using them.

Comment: Then why not declare a variable with `let` before the `try` or `if` and assign a value afterwards? In my opinion, it would make it more readable, being able to follow more easily in which block what variables are available and where they are declared within that same block.

Comment: @undefined it would require an additional line of code that doesn't do much

Comment: @alexpirine it defines a variable in the needed scope, which is how all (to my knowledge) other languages work and it makes little sense to be able to use a variable outside of the scope it was defined. This effectively removes the implicit functionality of `var` and replaces it with explicit functionality of `let`

Comment: @undefined yes, it sure helps with the scope, but again, sometimes fine-tuning the scope doesn't matter much. I mainly develop in Python, and we only have global and local scopes. In practice, 99.99% of the time we use the local scope which is more or less equivalent of using `var` in JavaScript.

So we have less control over it and linters have to work harder to spot issues, but it's not preventing us from writing software :)

However, I decided to use your approach by defining the correct scope with `let` when writing in JS. It seems to better fit “the JavaScript way of doing things”.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `var` if you want to deconstruct something into the function scope, for example a conditional:

```js
if (Math.random() > 0.5)
  var {a,b} = {a: 1, b: 2}
else 
  var {a,b} = {a: 10, b: 20}

// Some common logic on a and b
console.log(a, b)
```

With `let` you would have to write something like

```
let result;

if (Math.random() > 0.5)
  result = {a: 'foo', b: 'bar'}
else 
  result = {a: 'baz', b: 'qux'}

// Using const might make more sense here
let {a, b} = result; 
// Some common logic on a and b
console.log(a,b)
```

Comment: with `let`, one can change the property directly without causing error like `result = {a: 'foo', b: 'bar'}; result.a= poof`

Comment: Why not `let a, b;` then `a = "foo"`, `b = "bar"`? Seems simpler to me and makes it obvious in which block these variables can be used.

Answer (score 1):

## Don't Throw Out var

Stylistically, `var` has always, from the earliest days of JS, signaled "variable that belongs to a whole function." `var` attaches to the nearest enclosing function scope, no matter where it appears. That's true even if `var` appears inside a block:

```
function diff(x,y) {
    if (x > y) {
        var tmp = x;    // `tmp` is function-scoped
        x = y;
        y = tmp;
    }

    return y - x;
}
```

Even though `var` is inside a block, its declaration is function-scoped (to `diff(..)`), not block-scoped.

While you can declare `var` inside a block (and still have it be function-scoped), I would recommend against this approach except in a few specific cases. Otherwise, `var` should be reserved for use in the top-level scope of a function.

Why not just use `let` in that same location? Because `var` is visually distinct from `let` and therefore signals clearly, "this variable is function-scoped." Using `let` in the top-level scope, especially if not in the first few lines of a function, and when all the other declarations in blocks use `let`, does not visually draw attention to the difference with the function-scoped declaration.

In other words, I feel `var` better communicates function-scoped than `let` does, and `let` both communicates (and achieves!) block-scoping where `var` is insufficient. As long as your programs are going to need both function-scoped and block-scoped variables, the most sensible and readable approach is to use both `var` and `let` together, each for their own best purpose.

There are also other semantic and operational reasons to choose `var` or `let` in different scenarios.

| WARNING: |
| --- |
| My recommendation to use both `var` and `let` is clearly controversial and contradicts the majority. It's far more common to hear assertions like, "var is broken, let fixes it" and, "never use var, let is the replacement." Those opinions are valid, but they're merely opinions, just like mine. `var` is not factually broken or deprecated; it has worked since early JS and it will continue to work as long as JS is around. |

### Where To `let`?

My advice to reserve `var` for (mostly) only a top-level function scope means that most other declarations should use `let`. But you may still be wondering how to decide where each declaration in your program belongs?

[POLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) already guides you on those decisions, but let's make sure we explicitly state it. The way to decide is not based on which keyword you want to use. The way to decide is to ask, "What is the most minimal scope exposure that's sufficient for this variable?"

Once that is answered, you'll know if a variable belongs in a block scope or the function scope. If you decide initially that a variable should be block-scoped, and later realize it needs to be elevated to be function-scoped, then that dictates a change not only in the location of that variable's declaration, but also the declarator keyword used. The decision-making process really should proceed like that.

**If a declaration belongs in a block scope, use `let`. If it belongs in the function scope, use `var` (again, just my opinion).**

Why use `var` for function scoping? Because that's exactly what `var` does. There literally is no better tool for the job of function scoping a declaration than a declarator that has, for 25 years, done exactly that.

You could use `let` in this top-level scope, but it's not the best tool for that job. I also find that if you use `let` everywhere, then it's less obvious which declarations are designed to be localized and which ones are intended to be used throughout the function.

By contrast, I rarely use a `var` inside a block. That's what `let` is for. Use the best tool for the job. If you see a `let`, it tells you that you're dealing with a localized declaration. If you see `var`, it tells you that you're dealing with a function-wide declaration. Simple as that.

```
function getStudents(data) {
    var studentRecords = [];

    for (let record of data.records) {
        let id = `student-${ record.id }`;
        studentRecords.push({
            id,
            record.name
        });
    }

    return studentRecords;
}
```

The `studentRecords` variable is intended for use across the whole function. `var` is the best declarator to tell the reader that. By contrast, `record` and `id` are intended for use only in the narrower scope of the loop iteration, so `let` is the best tool for that job.

In addition to this best tool semantic argument, `var` has a few other characteristics that, in certain limited circumstances, make it more powerful.

One example is when a loop is exclusively using a variable, but its conditional clause cannot see block-scoped declarations inside the iteration:

```
function commitAction() {
    do {
        let result = commit();
        var done = result && result.code == 1;
    } while (!done);
}
```

Here, `result` is clearly only used inside the block, so we use `let`. But `done` is a bit different. It's only useful for the loop, but the while clause cannot see `let` declarations that appear inside the loop. So we compromise and use `var`, so that `done` is hoisted to the outer scope where it can be seen.

The alternative—declaring `done` outside the loop—separates it from where it's first used, and either necessitates picking a default value to assign, or worse, leaving it unassigned and thus looking ambiguous to the reader. I think `var` inside the loop is preferable here.

There are other nuances and scenarios when `var` turns out to offer some assistance, but I'm not going to belabor the point any further. The takeaway is that `var` can be useful in our programs alongside `let` (and the occasional `const`). Are you willing to creatively use the tools the JS language provides to tell a richer story to your readers?

Don't just throw away a useful tool like `var` because someone shamed you into thinking it wasn't cool anymore. Don't avoid `var` because you got confused once years ago. Learn these tools and use them each for what they're best at.

Source: [YDKJS by Kyle Simpson](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/2nd-ed/scope-closures)