# Why is var not deprecated?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, deprecated, var, let

Lately after ES6 released, many sources suggested that I use "const" and "let" instead of "var", and that I should stop using "var" in my JavaScript.

What I wonder is, if "var" has no advantage over "let" in all points of view, then why didn't they just fix var, or even deprecate "var" instead of letting them go along side each other?

Comment: Because changing or removing it would break about a billion lines of code.

Comment: `var` is a lot more useful than `let` when you want function scope and not block scope.

Comment: There are still uses for `var`.

Comment: @jhpratt: Like what?

Comment: What if I don't want block scope? I may very well desire the function scope of `var`, without having to say `let xyz` without a value just to define scope.

Comment: So your use case is declaring a variable inside a block and then using it outside of the block?

Comment: @jhpratt that wouldn't pass code review in any good company... and certainly is stamped on by any linter.

Comment: @Shadow I don't do that, just know others that do. I *always* use `let` and `const`.

Comment: @rockstar [Global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36140613/1048572) that need to be redeclable. Global variables with `let` and `const` suck.

Comment: "*I should stop using "var" in my JavaScript.*" - Have a look at [What is the use case for `var` in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31836796/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi: You're right, though as a use case, it doesn't seem very compelling because of alternatives. It's more of a *"I want to do things exactly like I've always done them*" case.

Comment: Turn the question around—what is the good of *let* and *const*? They provide zero additional functionality over *var*, they are simply tools to help programmers not make mistakes. If you don't care about block scope or constants, why use them? Does anyone use the same variable name twice in an execution context but in different block scopes? Would you really use `let i=0` in multiple *for* loops in the same context and rely on block scope to differentiate them? Or nested *for* loops? That makes debugging and maintenance harder, not easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the use case for var in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836796/what-is-the-use-case-for-var-in-es6)

Comment: They should remove this feature, even if it breaks lines of code. The industry should be forced to rewrite things that did not use good practice.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Backwards compatibility.

You're right in saying there is no real advantage to using [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) over [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) - if you define them at the start of a function their meaning is basically identical.

You're right that there is no real reason to write new code using `var` (except maybe [this](https://caniuse.com/#search=let), if relevant).

There are pages on the internet that are decades old though, and no one is going to rewrite them. There is nothing really to gain by removing `var` from the language. For languages like HTML and Javascript that are interpreted - backward compatability is absolutely mandatory.

That is also why they chose not to simply redefine `var`. Take the following example code;

```
// THIS IS AN EXAMPLE OF BAD CODE. DO NOT COPY AND PASTE THIS.
if (logic) {
    var output = "true"
} else {
    var output = "false"
}
console.log(output)
```

If `var` was changed to behave like `let` then the `console.log` would cause a reference error because of the scope difference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate it.
Yet your answer only solve one part of the question which is "why not deprecate var".
How about refactoring the "var" from the beginning and not introducing any "let"? Are there good reasons for it?

Comment: Again, backwards compatibility. If people were using `var` in the horrendous way described in the comments of your question (and it does happen), then that code would change meaning and break, probably without warning as far as the developer who wrote it is concerned.

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: I always consider the example you show to be bad form.  Better to declare the variable at a higher scope.  Which means I don't think that's a good example of a good use for `var`.

Comment: I agree - perhaps I should make that more obvious. It is however an example of why just changing `var` to mean `let` is a bad idea, which was the intent.

Comment: Backwards compatibility is the ultimate reason of all the sh*tshow in the programming world.

Answer (score 1):

I believe sometimes you need to redeclare a variable to write less code.

**One example** is this function that generates a unique id:

```
function makeUniqueId(takenIds) {
  do {
    var id = Number.parseInt(Math.random() * 10);
  } while (takenIds.includes(id))
}
```

Which may be invoked like that

```
makeUniqueId([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

Here I declare `id` variable simply inside `do` block and it get's "hoisted" to the function scope. That would cause an error if I used `let`, because `while` block wouldn't see the variable from the `do` block. Of course I could declate `let` before `do..while`, but that would create the same function scoped variable with extra line of code.

**Another example** is when you copypaste code to devtools console and every time variables get redeclared.

**One more example**. What if you want to keep your variable declarations close to their usages but still treat them as function globals? If you use `let` in this fashion, you'll get rather confusing expirience in dev tools (all those Block, Block scopes).
[image]

But `var` 'keeps' them together in one 'Local' list:
[image]

Comment: "*As you can see, id is probably going to be redeclared many times…*" No it wont. Declarations are processed exactly once when control enters a new execution context (or block for block-scoped declarations). The variable *id* exists with function scope before any of the body of *makeUniqueId* is executed. There is no *while* block, there is a *while* expression and you're right, the scope of a *let* declaration in a *do..while* loop doesn't extend to the *while* condition so *id* would be out of scope if declared using *let* in the *do* block.

Comment: Thanks for catching that!

Comment: All those use cases are not sufficient reasons to keep var around. It brings more confusion and bugs than benefits. Simplification would be much appreciated.

Comment: All examples demonstrates exactly the opposite: [ex. 1]: the logic of _id_ is to be in the external scope, and it must be declared there, not in _do{}_, then use **let** above; [ex. 2]: copy-pasting re-declared variables is extremely dangerous; using **let** will show explicitly the issues; [ex. 3] is similar to 1: you say that you want to declare a variable close to its usage, but you want treat it as global: therefore the declaration must be in the global scope. In general, it isn't wise to use global variable, unless in a Module pattern, i.e. a **const** declared object.

Answer (score -1):

Everything has their own advantages and disadvantages using var const and let is dependent on their use cases.

```
var
```

Variable declarations are processed before the execution of the code.
The scope of a JavaScript variable declared with var is its current execution context.
The scope of a JavaScript variable declared outside the function is global.

```
let
```

The let statement allows you to create a variable with the scope limited to the block on which it is used.

```
const
```

const statement values can be assigned once and they cannot be reassigned. The scope of const statement works similar to let statements.

I hope you understand.

Comment: You didn't list any advantages for `var`. You can use `let` at the function or global level too, so where's the advantage, beyond doing something unpleasant like declaring a `var` in a block but then using it outside that block.

Comment: "*Variable declarations are processed before the execution of the code*" - [the same is true for `let` and `const`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/1048572)

Comment: Note that "variable declarations" includes *let* and *const* (per [*ECMA-262 §13.3.1*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations)), they're all processed before code is executed (but assignments are made when the code is executed). ;-)