# Jquery .GET function from JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The jQuery below illustrates how I get the products from https://dummyjson.com/products. However, I don't know how to iterate the loop to retrieve each of the 30 products in the link and the details of each product.

```
$.get("https://dummyjson.com/products/1")
    .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

        console.log("typeof(data) is: " + typeof(data));
        console.log("data is: "+ data);
        console.log(data.length);
  
        var result = [];
        result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));  
        console.log(typeof(result));
        console.log(result.length);
        var keys = Object.keys(result);

        keys.forEach(function (key) {
            console.log("forEach");
            console.log(key, result[key]);
            //console.log(result[0]);
        });

    })

    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("error");
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
        
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through the object itself instead of the keys. Also, use `let` instead of `var` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47465515/why-is-var-not-deprecated)).

```js
$.get("https://dummyjson.com/products/1")
  .done(function(data) {
    let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    $.each( result, function( key, value ) {
      console.log( key + ": " + value );
    });
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For multiple products you need another for loop to iterate through each product:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get("https://dummyjson.com/products")
    .done(function(data) {
      let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
      $.each(result, function( key, products) {
        for (let i = 0; i < products.length; ++i) {
          console.log(products[i].id);
          console.log(products[i].title);
          console.log(products[i].description);
        }
      });
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. How do you console.log each product details?

Comment: The console shows products: [object Object], [object Object], ... Sorry for my ignorance. I am taking a part time course in javascript and it is a crash course. So, I am learning on my own.

Comment: You mean you want to get each product from this url: https://dummyjson.com/products instead of getting the https://dummyjson.com/products/1?

Comment: if the URL is changed to https://dummyjson.com/products where there are 30 products instead of 1 product, what needs to be done to your codes? Thanks.

Comment: Edited my answer. Check it out.

Comment: It does not seem to work. console.log(products[i].id), console.log(products[i].title) and console.log(products[i].description) are undefined.

Comment: It should work, if you run the code here, you get the results correctly. Try to comment out your code and copy paste mine first. Also don't forget to paste the jquery link.

Comment: You have helped me to understand how to use jQuery to parse JSON data. The JSON data from https://dummyjson.com/products is different from other JSON data that I have successfully parsed. I determined to understand why my codes didn't work, and now I could understand this topic. All thanks to you!

Comment: You are welcome. Can be tricky, depending on the data, but JSON is always a good thing to work with :)

Answer (score 0):

Thats is totally depends upon how was your reponse are.

**If  your response like this.**

```
{
   "status": true,
   "data" : [
     {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "xyz",      
     },
     {
         "id": 2,
         "name": "xyz",      
     }
   ]
}
```

then you have to use following code:

```
$.get('/your-url', function(response) {
    if(response.status) {
       $.each(response.data, function(index, item) {
           console.log(item);
       })        
    } else {
       alert('Your API sent false status')
    }
})
```

**Otherwise your response something like this.**

```
[ 
     {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "xyz",      
     },
     {
         "id": 2,
         "name": "xyz",      
     }
]
```

then you have to use following code:

```
$.get('/your-url', function(response) {
    $.each(response, function(index, item) {
       console.log(item);
    })  
})
```