# Is it safe to use const and let in Node-RED

Tags: node-red

When I am reading official docs, reading/watching recent unofficial guides, etc. I see `var` used all over the place inside of function nodes, I very rarely see the use of `const` and `let`.

It could be due to Node-RED launching prior to ES6, however, in the chance that there could there be an underlying scoping issue that is solved by using var, I need to ask.

Is it safe to use the newer `const` and `let` variable declarations in Node-RED?

Comment: If `const` and `let` are newer, that's all the explanation you need.

Comment: Node-RED initial release was 2013. ES6 with `let` and `const` was 2015. Probably everything you need to know right there

Comment: @JohnGordon Perhaps, although, even the newer guides and tutorials are continuing the same behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is var not deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47465515/why-is-var-not-deprecated)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the modern `const` and `let`.

The reason really is that it predates ES6. As to why the community keep making guides with the old `var` declaration, it is a mystery.

here is a discussion on Node-RED's board with a similar topic that urges the use of `const` and `let`.
https://discourse.nodered.org/t/where-to-use-let-and-where-to-use-var-in-a-function-node/33174

Comment: It's not a mystery, it's just that the community has plenty of other things to work on that have more impact. All the documentation is OpenSource as well, feel free to open a Pull Request to update it if you feel it needs it.

Comment: @hardillb A good suggestion, I think I will do that at some point if I can find the time. I would like to kindly point out however, that I didn't mention the official docs being a mystery for using var.